# Time accumulation

Tags: php, time, timer, precision

Something I've noticed while working on a timer is that the accumulative time appears to increase further on top on normal time.

Here is a simple example:

```
$time = microtime(true);

for (;;) {
    time_nanosleep(2, 0);
    var_dump(microtime(true) - $time);
}
```

Now I would expect that the calculation output by the `var_dump` would increment by two seconds, which it does a close precision, but the weird thing is that 4-point precision increases as well:

```
float(2.0001111030579)
float(4.000256061554)
float(6.0003678798676)
float(8.0004849433899)
float(10.000600099564)
float(12.000720024109)
float(14.000848054886)
float(16.000955104828)
float(18.001054048538)
float(20.001163005829)
float(22.001266002655)
float(24.001379013062)
float(26.001489877701)
float(28.001588106155)
float(30.001708984375)
float(32.001836061478)
```

This to my mind after an extended period would add an additional second to the count, which doesn't seem possible given I'm checking the system time every two seconds.

There might be a legitimate explanation where by this timer is in fact accurate, but I do not know what it is. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Why is that weird? Every line of code takes time to execute.

Comment: @jeroen Ye, I just went away and realized the problem isn't the way the time is calculated.  My mind was fixed on the idea that the check was somehow exempt.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the realization in the comments the following code at least guarantees <strike>accuracy</strike> consistency to 0.0001 of a second:

```
$interval = 2000000;
$thisInterval = $interval;

$time = microtime(true);

for (;;) {
    time_nanosleep(
        floor($thisInterval / 1000000),
        fmod($thisInterval, 1000000) * 1000
    );
    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $time;
    $thisInterval = $interval - (fmod($elapsed, $interval / 1000000) * 1000000);

    var_dump($elapsed);
}
```